# How to tell nginx to honor backend's cache? uWSGI

Tags: nginx, cache, uwsgi, http-caching

There's a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/454150/how-to-tell-nginx-to-honor-backends-cache) but solution there doesn't work for me.

We have nginx and uWSGI ad backend. We need nginx to cache the backend response according to what is in the response header.

For example, I run `curl -I https://example.com/api/project_data/`. Using `tcpdump` I see the backend responds:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept, Accept-Language, Origin
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
X-Request-ID: 6aa...0d99
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie:  longterm_session=45c6...67; Domain=example.com;
```

Nevertheless, the response isn't cached and nginx knoks to the backend every time the request received.

The nginx config:

```
http {
        uwsgi_cache_path /var/local/nginx_cache levels=2:2 use_temp_path=off inactive=1h keys_zone=mycache:20m ;
....

  server {
    ....
    uwsgi_cache mycache;
    uwsgi_cache_key "$request_method$request_uri";

    location /api/project_data/ {
      add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
      add_header Pragma "public";
      uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:49002;
      include uwsgi_params;

      uwsgi_cache mycache;
      uwsgi_cache_key "$request_method$request_uri";

    }
```

I duplicated `uwsgi_cache` just to be on the safe side because afaik some directives are not inherited into `location`. Also, there's `x-cache: MISS` in the response nginx sends to the client.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx docs [explicitly state](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_cache_valid) that

> If the header includes the “Set-Cookie” field, such a response will not be cached.

You'd have to make your application not to send cookies for the corresponding response to be cached, for obvious reasons - cookies are extra data to both client and server, same as e.g. response body.